# Angular - Adjust two way binded input element's height according to the length of its content

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I want to make **the height of my input text adjusted to its text content**. I can easily achieve that when the user is filling the content by triggering the `(input)` event, which calls my `adjustHeight` function which **updates the height of the input element using the** `scrollHeight`.

Code example below:

```
 <textarea #myLabel
       (input)="adjustHeight(myLabel)"
       [(ngModel)]="labelValue">
 </textarea>


 adjustHeight(element: HTMLElement) {
   element.style.height = "5px";
   element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight)+"px";
 }
```

This works fine when the user is filling the input element, **but when the input text is rendered with an already filled `labelValue`, (coming from an API response) the height of the textarea is not changed dynamically since no (input) event gets triggered**.

I tried to use `(ngModelChange)` event but it does not seem to be triggered. Is there any other event that could be binded to the input element to take care of its height **on rendering**? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**template:**

```
<textarea #myLabel
    [style.height]="getHeight(myLabel)" 
    [(ngModel)]="labelValue">
</textarea>
```

**typescript:**

```
public getHeight(element: HTMLElement): string {
    return element.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

this way, the style will change whenever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting by initializing **labelValue** to *''* first (when you declare it), and then assign its value as you should be doing now.

Comment: Thanks for your response, well the `labelValue` is a property of an object that is filled from the response of an API request like `this.question = <api response>` where `question` object contains the `labelValue` property so I think it does not matter whether the labelValue property is initialized to '' at first